# Send signal to other process

Tags: linux, go, signals

since `os/signal` is only for handling of incoming signals I'm asking if there is a native way to send signals to other processes?

Edit: The process I want to mange is nginx. My Go application should listen for some events and then send a `SIGHUP` to nginx to reload its configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366550/go-inter-process-communication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have created process with os.StartProcess or exec.Command you can use [Process.Signal](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal) method:

```
cmd := exec.Command("CmdPath", "-param1", param1)
cmd.Process.Signal(signal)
```

For external process You should know it's process id (PID) and then call for example:

```
syscall.Kill(pid,syscall.SIGHUP)
```

Signal is a standart UNIX "kill" syscall, if you know a pid of the process, you can simply make a syscall with 
https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Kill

Comment: The other process is not started by my Go app. It's independently started

Comment: Do you know processId ? You should find it prom from process list or in some ngnix.pid file - and make syscall.Signal(ngnixPid,SIG_HUP)

Comment: misspelling: syscall.Kill (pid,syscall.SIGHUP) ofcourse

Comment: ah perfect :) That's what I was looking for I guess. Feel free to add is as an answer